# Android debug and release builds

Tags: android, gradle, build

Android студия в debug режиме собирает проект на ура, но в release у нее не получается. В проекте используется нативный код. Gradle выводит следующую ошибку:

```
Execution failed for task ':myapp:packageRelease'.

> Failed to add
> C:\Users\BaJIuK\Documents\android\main\MainProjects\myapp\app\build\intermediates\ndk\release\lib\armeabi\myapp.so
```

Вот мой gradle.build файл:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

android {
    compileOptions.encoding = 'ISO-8859-1'
    compileSdkVersion CompiledSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion BuildToolsVersion

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "myapp"
        minSdkVersion MinSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion TargetSdkVersion
        versionCode 10
        versionName "1.0.2b"
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("..\\release.keystore")
            storePassword "***"
            keyAlias "***"
            keyPassword "***"
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }

    android {
        sourceSets.main {
            jni.srcDirs = []
            jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/libs'
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'

        }
    }

    splits {
        abi {
            enable false // enable ABI split feature to create one APK per ABI
            universalApk true //generate an additional APK that targets all the ABIs
        }
    }
    project.ext.versionCodes = ['armeabi':1, 'armeabi-v7a':2, 'arm64-v8a':3, 'mips':5, 'mips64':6, 'x86':8, 'x86_64':9]
    android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            output.versionCodeOverride =
                    project.ext.versionCodes.get(output.getFilter(com.android.build.OutputFile.ABI), 0) * 1000000 + android.defaultConfig.versionCode
        }
    }
}

crashlytics {
    enableNdk true
    androidNdkOut 'src/main/obj'
    androidNdkLibsOut 'src/main/libs'
}

dependencies {

    compile Dependencies.appCompat
    compile Dependencies.recyclerView
    compile Dependencies.cardView
    compile Dependencies.playServices

    compile files('libs/dropbox-android-sdk-1.6.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/json_simple-1.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/kxml2-2.3.0.jar')

    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.2@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics-ndk:1.1.1@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
}

task buildNative(type: Exec, description: 'Compile JNI source via NDK') {
    android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        def ndkDir = project.plugins.findPlugin('com.android.application').sdkHandler.getNdkFolder()
        commandLine "$ndkDir/ndk-build.cmd", '-C', file('src/main').absolutePath

    }
}

task cleanNative(type: Exec, description: 'Clean JNI object files') {
    android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        def ndkDir = project.plugins.findPlugin('com.android.application').sdkHandler.getNdkFolder()
        commandLine "$ndkDir/ndk-build.cmd",
                'NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null',
                'NDK_APPLICATION_MK=src/main/jni/Application.mk',
                'APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=src/main/jni/Android.mk',
                "NDK_OUT=$buildDir/intermediates/ndk/${variant.dirName}/obj",
                "NDK_LIBS_OUT=$buildDir/intermediates/ndk/${variant.dirName}/lib",
                'clean'
    }
}

clean.dependsOn 'cleanNative'

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn buildNative
}
```

В чем проблема и как ее решить?

Comment: А файл-то существует по этому пути?   (...ndk\release\lib\armeabi\myapp.so)

Comment: Существует. Проверил, есть *.so файлы для всех типов процессоров.